# Convert “document.getElementById” directly into jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, getelementbyid

I'm using the [qq.uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) class and here is a portion of my code:

```
function createUploader(elementId){
   var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById(elementId),

        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){

            if (responseJSON.success) {
                $("#"+elementId + ".qq-upload-button").remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can see the line `$("#"+elementId + ".qq-upload-button").remove();` is not going to work, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do. I have multiple uploaders on the page so I need to target specific ones separately instead of just the class.

(I just also realized the plugin creates a set #id which will be repeated throughout the page.. so I'm also curious about good jquery file upload plugins that work well with multiple instances per page with only one file uploaded per instance?)

Comment: Why won't this work? You don't even need the class, since element IDs should be unique on a page.

Comment: Re-using "id" values among multiple elements on a page will cause problems.

Comment: not a fan of uploadify using flash..

Comment: Jquery File Upload:  http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload non-flash, uses all available browser features like drag & drop, falls back on iframes for bad old browsers.

Comment: Is your "elementId" variable still known in the scope of the onComplete function? Try adding an: alert(elementId); to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = '#' + elementId +'.qq-upload-button';
if (responseJSON.success) {
      $(id).remove();
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as what's in the original question.

Comment: "Almost the same" mostly means "not even close" when programming.

Comment: Except it is functionally exactly the same, and still incorporates the imponderable "id.class" selector notion.

Comment: @Jules if yours were to work, then so would the original, as your change makes no material difference to the function he posted.

Comment: @Pointy I have experiences with the functionality not working the way he did it. While it always works for me when doing it the way I posted.

Comment: @jamietre I agree he is not using the id (which should be an unique identifier) correctly, but that is irrelevant to the question he asked.

Comment: @Jules, so how does your answer solve his problem? It results in exactly the same selector his code produces. All you have done is put it in a variable first. The id issue is the actual root of the question he asked, per his edit (the elements produced have the same ids). So ignoring the fact that you will have unpredictable results because this violates specs, there is nothing in your code that addresses his problem in any way. Because it is logically identical.